# How to parse a JSON object with nested arrays in google apps script

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm having difficulty parsing a JSON string with nested arrays. here is an example of the JSON

```
var json = {
"id": "123456", 
"cost_name":"john", 
"line_item":[{
"item_name":"table", "quantity":"1", "properties":[{
"color":"black", "style":"rustic"
}]},
 {
"item_name":"chair", "quantity":"3", "properties":[{
"color":"white", "style":"modern"
}]}],
"address":"123_street"
 }
```

I need to get the `item_name` and `quantity` of each `line_item` and I also need the `color` and `style` of each

I'm receiving this JSON from a webhook so the order is never the same.

**ADDED CONTEXT:** (@Taineke's request)

I'm trying to write this to a google sheet with apps script here is my code.

```
function doPost(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  
//extract data here
var I= item_name;
var Q = quantity;
var C = color;
var S = style;
  
  ss.appendRow([I,Q,C,S])
}
```

**HERE IS UPDATED `e.postData.contents` (that @Tanaike) requested from a test webhook**

```
{"id":3175309607101,"email":"sample@sample.com","closed_at":null,"created_at":"2021-01-05T21:35:06-05:00","updated_at":"2021-01-05T21:35:08-05:00","number":1586,"note":"","token":"3491883c672f110eaab82f8dd8080052","gateway":null,"test":false,"total_price":"0.00","subtotal_price":"0.00","total_weight":0,"total_tax":"0.00","taxes_included":false,"currency":"USD","financial_status":"paid","confirmed":true,"total_discounts":"18.00","total_line_items_price":"18.00","cart_token":"a3c9cb049e2f631a8393cf37547623e2","buyer_accepts_marketing":false,"name":"#2586","referring_site":"","landing_site":"\/","cancelled_at":null,"cancel_reason":null,"total_price_usd":"0.00","checkout_token":"11d27a9399b514cb6ba246a3fffc7b23","reference":null,"user_id":null,"location_id":null,"source_identifier":null,"source_url":null,"processed_at":"2021-01-05T21:35:02-05:00","device_id":null,"phone":null,"customer_locale":"en","app_id":580111,"browser_ip":"172.58.238.224","client_details":{"accept_language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","browser_height":657,"browser_ip":"172.58.238.224","browser_width":1349,"session_hash":null,"user_agent":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/87.0.4280.88 Safari\/537.36"},"landing_site_ref":null,"order_number":2586,"discount_applications":[{"type":"discount_code","value":"100.0","value_type":"percentage","allocation_method":"across","target_selection":"all","target_type":"line_item","code":"adina"}],"discount_codes":[{"code":"adina","amount":"18.00","type":"percentage"}],"note_attributes":[{"name":"Checkout-Method","value":"pickup"},{"name":"Pickup-Location-Id","value":"105225"},{"name":"Pickup-Location-Company","value":"Evergreen Monsey"},{"name":"Pickup-Location-Address-Line-1","value":"59 NY-59"},{"name":"Pickup-Location-City","value":"Monsey"},{"name":"Pickup-Location-Region","value":"New York"},{"name":"Pickup-Location-Postal-Code","value":"10952"},{"name":"Pickup-Location-Country","value":"United States"}],"payment_gateway_names":[],"processing_method":"free","checkout_id":18478127907005,"source_name":"web","fulfillment_status":null,"tax_lines":[],"tags":"","contact_email":"sample@sample.com","order_status_url":"https:\/\/labelitlabels.com\/26375225421\/orders\/3491883c672f110eaab82f8dd8080052\/authenticate?key=46788d0320dc9961fed8c81630484581","presentment_currency":"USD","total_line_items_price_set":{"shop_money":{"amount":"18.00","currency_code":"USD"},"presentment_money":{"amount":"18.00","currency_code":"USD"}},"total_discounts_set":{"shop_money":{"amount":"18.00","currency_code":"USD"},"presentment_money":{"amount":"18.00","currency_code":"USD"}},"total_shipping_price_set":{"shop_money":{"amount":"0.00","currency_code":"USD"},"presentment_money":{"amount":"0.00","currency_code":"USD"}},"subtotal_price_set":{"shop_money":{"amount":"0.00","currency_code":"USD"},"presentment_money":{"amount":"0.00","currency_code":"USD"}},"total_price_set":{"shop_money":{"amount":"0.00","currency_code":"USD"},"presentment_money":{"amount":"0.00","currency_code":"USD"}},"total_tax_set":{"shop_money":{"amount":"0.00","currency_code":"USD"},"presentment_money":{"amount":"0.00","currency_code":"USD"}},"line_items":[{"id":9102143324349,"variant_id":31929214402637,"title":"Bold Monogram","quantity":30,"sku":"L21","variant_title":"2\"*2\" $0.60","vendor":"Label It Labels","fulfillment_service":"manual","product_id":4374255960141,"requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"gift_card":false,"name":"Bold Monogram - 2\"*2\" $0.60","variant_inventory_management":null,"properties":[{"name":"Shape","value":"Square Shape"},{"name":"Choose Background","value":"#030000"},{"name":"Initial","value":"D"},{"name":"_font size Initial","value":"300.00"},{"name":"Choose Text Color","value":"White"},{"name":"Spell Name","value":"DREW FAMILY"},{"name":"_font size Spell Name","value":"33.00"},{"name":"Additional Text (optional)","value":"dairy cholov yisroel"},{"name":"_font size Additional Text (optional)","value":"12.00"},{"name":"_6","value":"PROOF"},{"name":"_Preview","value":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0263\/7522\/5421\/uploads\/23b9fb4ba8eb01b7ff717d39d9672c2d.png?format=png\u0026png"},{"name":"_pdf","value":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0263\/7522\/5421\/uploads\/5c0c23d462aa998831b0f79aabd0b9eb.pdf"},{"name":"_pplr_preview","value":"_Preview"},{"name":"_ZapietId","value":"a3c9cb049e2f631a8393cf37547623e2"}],"product_exists":true,"fulfillable_quantity":30,"grams":0,"price":"0.60","total_discount":"0.00","fulfillment_status":null,"price_set":{"shop_money":{"amount":"0.60","currency_code":"USD"},"presentment_money":{"amount":"0.60","currency_code":"USD"}},"total_discount_set":{"shop_money":{"amount":"0.00","currency_code":"USD"},"presentment_money":{"amount":"0.00","currency_code":"USD"}},"discount_allocations":[{"amount":"18.00","discount_application_index":0,"amount_set":{"shop_money":{"amount":"18.00","currency_code":"USD"},"presentment_money":{"amount":"18.00","currency_code":"USD"}}}],"duties":[],"admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/LineItem\/9102143324349","tax_lines":[{"title":"NJ State Tax","price":"0.00","rate":0.06625,"price_set":{"shop_money":{"amount":"0.00","currency_code":"USD"},"presentment_money":{"amount":"0.00","currency_code":"USD"}}}],"origin_location":{"id":1809674076237,"country_code":"US","province_code":"NJ","name":"Label It Labels.","address1":"155 Pressburg Ln","address2":"","city":"Lakewood","zip":"08701"}}],"fulfillments":[],"refunds":[],"total_tip_received":"0.0","original_total_duties_set":null,"current_total_duties_set":null,"admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Order\/3175309607101","shipping_lines":[{"id":2654542987453,"title":"Pick up in Lakewood only","price":"0.00","code":"Pick up in Lakewood only","source":"shopify","phone":null,"requested_fulfillment_service_id":null,"delivery_category":null,"carrier_identifier":null,"discounted_price":"0.00","price_set":{"shop_money":{"amount":"0.00","currency_code":"USD"},"presentment_money":{"amount":"0.00","currency_code":"USD"}},"discounted_price_set":{"shop_money":{"amount":"0.00","currency_code":"USD"},"presentment_money":{"amount":"0.00","currency_code":"USD"}},"discount_allocations":[],"tax_lines":[]}],"billing_address":{"first_name":"John","address1":"123 street","phone":"(234) 567-8901","city":"Any City","zip":"08701","province":"New Jersey","country":"United States","last_name":"Smith","address2":"","company":null,"latitude":40.0963651,"longitude":-74.2067389,"name":"John Smith","country_code":"US","province_code":"NJ"},"shipping_address":{"first_name":"John","address1":"123 street","phone":"(234) 567-8901","city":"Any City","zip":"08701","province":"New Jersey","country":"United States","last_name":"Smith","address2":"","company":null,"latitude":40.0963651,"longitude":-74.2067389,"name":"John Smith","country_code":"US","province_code":"NJ"},"customer":{"id":4602994983101,"email":"sample@sample.com","accepts_marketing":false,"created_at":"2021-01-05T21:31:39-05:00","updated_at":"2021-01-05T21:35:07-05:00","first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith","orders_count":1,"state":"disabled","total_spent":"0.00","last_order_id":3175309607101,"note":null,"verified_email":true,"multipass_identifier":null,"tax_exempt":false,"phone":null,"tags":"","last_order_name":"#2586","currency":"USD","accepts_marketing_updated_at":"2021-01-05T21:31:39-05:00","marketing_opt_in_level":null,"admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Customer\/4602994983101","default_address":{"id":5617895145661,"customer_id":4602994983101,"first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith","company":null,"address1":"123 street","address2":"","city":"Any City","province":"New Jersey","country":"United States","zip":"08701","phone":"(234) 567-8901","name":"John Smith","province_code":"NJ","country_code":"US","country_name":"United States","default":true}}}
```

**HERE IS MY LATEST CODE.** It works but maybe can be cleaner and faster. which I'm having issues with Shopify's 5 second wait time to refiring if no response is recieved.

```
function doPost(e){
  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 
  var l = data.line_items.length; 
 
  for (var i=0;i<l;i++){
  var prop = data.line_items[i].properties;


  if (prop.length>0){
  var pdf = prop.find(function(x) {if(x.name == "_pdf") return x});
  if (!pdf){pdf = "Prop not found";}else{pdf = pdf.value};
  
  var shape = prop.find(function(x) {if(x.name.toLowerCase() == "shape") return x});
  if (!shape){shape = "Prop not found";}else{shape = shape.value};
  

  }else{
  var pdf = "N/A"
  var shape = "N/A"
  };


  var count = "Item "+ (i+1) + " of " + l;
  var qty = data.line_items[i].quantity;
  var title = data.line_items[i].title;
  var id = data.id.toString();
  var email = data.email;
  var totalPrice = data.total_price;
  var discounts = data.total_discounts;
  var acceptAds = data.buyer_accepts_marketing;
  var orderStatus = data.order_status_url;
  var addr = data.shipping_address.address1;
  var city = data.shipping_address.city;
  var state = data.shipping_address.province;
  var zip = data.shipping_address.zip;
  var phone = data.shipping_address.phone;
  var firstName = data.shipping_address.first_name;
  var lastName = data.shipping_address.last_name;
  var orderNum = data.name;
  var d = new Date(data.created_at).toLocaleString();
  ss.appendRow([d,orderNum,email,count,title,shape,qty,totalPrice,discounts,pdf,firstName,lastName,addr,city,state,zip,phone,orderStatus]);
  
if (pdf != "N/A"){
if (pdf != "Prop not found"){
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(pdf);
  var blob = res.getBlob();
  var createFile = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-').createFile(blob.getAs('application/pdf'));
  var fileName = orderNum + " " + qty;
  createFile.setName(fileName);
}}
  };
}
```

Comment: Hmm, is that exactly how it looks? That's not JSON

Comment: its in Google apps script and its after I parsed it  `var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);` and then I wrote it too the sheet

Comment: About your updated question, I thought that `"line_ite":[{` might be `"line_item":[{`. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike yes I corrected it and added context see edited question

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your updated question, I added one more sample script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your updated question, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike I tried your script but it did not work. Let me mention that the amount of `line_items` is dynamic meaning it can be 1 or 3 depending on the order. Thank You! Also can you write the script in an easier to modify way since the above is a sample and I may need more fields in final product Thanks again

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `it did not work`, I cannot understand your situation, and also, I cannot understand about `Let me mention,,,`. In my proposed script, even when the length of `line_items` is changed, the script works. So I cannot understand about your current issue. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. In order to correctly understand about your updated question, can you provide your current script and sample value of `e.postData.contents` for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike No worries, when I tried your script a fired a test webhook, nothing got written to sheet. I placed the json object that you wrote in your answer and ran the function manually and it did write to the sheet so seems I'm not understanding the JSON string structure that I'm getting from the webhook. here is sample of what I got when I put `data` from `var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);` directly in to the sheet `{total_weight=0.0, note=null, line_items=[Ljava.lang.Object;@217f77a1, processed_at=null, shipping_lines=[Ljava.lang.Object;@7c11d14b, test=true}`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. In your replying, the sample value of `var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);` is shown. In my replying, I asked about the value of `e.postData.contents`. Because in your replying, all values cannot be seen. I apologize for this. So can you add the sample value of `e.postData.contents` to your question? By this, I would like to try to replicate your issue. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: the values can be found here https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/events/webhook# I'm trying to write data received from a Shopify Order webhook, and I need to get to `line_items` and  `properties` of the `line_items`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed your replying just now. I apologize for this. When you replying, when you add `@udername`, we can know your replying. About your replying, unfortunately, I couldn't understand about the sample values. I apologize for this. So can you add the sample value of `e.postData.contents` to your question instead of `JSON.parse(e.postData.contents)`? By this, I would like to try to replicate your issue. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your issue?

Comment: @Tanaike I added it to the question

Comment: Thank you for adding the information. When I saw your sample value you added, `properties` in `line_items` has no values. And, your additional value is different from the value of your initial question. So I cannot understand about the result value you expect. I apologize for this. So, can you provide the result value, you expect, from your added value? By this, I would like to modify the script.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for your patience. I updated the `e.postData.contents` in the question. The values I need are for now are `_pdf` and `Shape` which are in the `properties` array. Please note these can be dynamic, so if a value is not there it should not cause an error. These values are examples that I know I need, but in the future I may need other ones, but I'm hoping I can understand how to modify your code to my needs. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: @Tanaike Hi, Thanks for your modification. I think it did work but only for one `line_item`. I'm also not such an expert coder, and I am going to need to modify it to my final needs. I was successful in getting it to work, maybe in not such an efficient way. Additionally Shopify has a minimum 5 second response time causing the webhook to re-fire untill a response is received, causing me issues. Maybe you can suggest ways to simplify my code to make it faster and cleaner but keeping it simple enough to edit and modify according to future needs. Thanks again (see code in question)

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for all your help, I did as you requested here is the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65617637/quicken-google-apps-script-so-i-can-return-success-response-within-shopify-5-sec

Comment: @jack Thank you for your response. When I saw your new question now, it seems that the discussions has already been advanced. I would like to respect those discussions. I believe that they will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought that from your title, in your `json`, `=` might be `:` in the value. If it's so, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
var json = {
  "id": 123456,
  "cost_name": "john",
  "line_item": [
    {
      "item_name": "table",
      "quantity": 1,
      "properties": [
        {
          "color": "black",
          "style": "rustic"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "item_name": "chair",
      "quantity": 3,
      "properties": [
        {
          "color": "white",
          "style": "modern"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "address": "123_street"
};

const res = json.line_item.map(({item_name, quantity, properties: [{color, style}]}) => [item_name, quantity, color, style]);
console.log(res)
```

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the result format you expect. So in above sample script, each values are put in an array. If above result format is not the result you expected, can you provide the sample output values? By this, I would like to modify it.
- In this case, please enable V8 runtime at the script editor.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Added 1:

From your updated question, I understood that `data` is `json` in your above script and you want to append the values of `item_name, quantity, color, style` to the active sheet in Google Spreadsheet. For this, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var res = data.line_item.map(({item_name, quantity, properties: [{color, style}]}) => [item_name, quantity, color, style]);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

#### Note:

- **It seems that you are using Web Apps. In this case, when the script of Web Apps is modified, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be carful this.**

### Added 2:

From your updated question, it was found that your additional value is different from your initial question. And, I understood that you wanted to retrieve the values of `Shape` and `_pdf` in `properties` from the added value. So in this case, I would like to modify the script as follows.

#### Sample script:

In this case, `data` is your added values. Please be careful this.

```
function doPost(e) {
  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  
  const checkNames = ["Shape", "_pdf"];
  const res = data.line_items.reduce((ar, {properties}) => {
    if (properties) {
      properties.forEach(({name, value}) => {
        if (checkNames.includes(name)) ar.push([name, value]);
      });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (res.length > 0) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
  }
}
```

- In this script, when the values of `properties` are not existing, `setValues` is not run. By this, no error occurs.

#### Note:

- In this script, your added value is used. So when the structure of value is different, the script might not be able to be used. So please be careful this.
- **It seems that you are using Web Apps. In this case, when the script of Web Apps is modified, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be carful this.**

Comment: @bottledatthesource About `json.line_item what is this? is this a module/package?`, the sample value of `var json = {,,,}` is from this question. My answer is for "How to parse a JSON object with nested arrays in google apps script". So how about asking your question to the owner of this question?